# Ruby: On what defining a class evaluates to

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, why does defining a class evaluate to `nil`? Same goes for defining a method: why does it evaluate to `nil`? Wouldn't it be useful if defining a class would evaluate as the class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In Ruby, why does defining a class evaluate to `nil`?

It doesn't.

First off, in Ruby you don't define a class, you execute a class body. Secondly, executing a class body does *not* evaluate to `nil` as you claim, it evaluates to the value of the last expression inside the class body. This is perfectly consistent with executing a module body and executing a method body.

See, for example:

```
class Foo
  'Hello'
end
# => 'Hello'
```

> Same goes for defining a method: why does it evaluate to `nil`?

Actually, it doesn't either. Defining a method evaluates to an implementation-defined value. The reason why it evaluates to an implementation-defined value is that so far the Ruby community hasn't reached a consensus on what it should return.

Some argue that it should evaluate to the `CompiledMethod` object corresponding to that method. That's what Rubinius does. However, there is a problem with this: not all Ruby implementations compile their methods. And not all of them that *do* compile them, compile them at definition time. JRuby, for example, only compiles them when they are executed, more precisely *after* they have been executed 20 times. Sometimes it doesn't compile them *at all*, for example in environments where compilation is forbidden such as Google App Engine. Also, not all Ruby implementations do have a Ruby representation for their compiled methods. And even if they did, their compiled methods are vastly different: Rubinius's compiled methods are Rubinius bytecode, YARV's compiled methods are YARV bytecode, JRuby's compiled methods are JVM bytecode, IronRuby's compiled methods are DLR trees. And of course the most widely used implementation, MRI, doesn't even *have* a compiler.

Others say, it should evaluate to the `UnboundMethod` object corresponding to that method. Here, the problem is that there is no single `UnboundMethod` object corresponding to a method. There's infinitely many of them. Ruby methods *aren't* objects. They can be *converted* to objects, but they aren't objects themselves. And when they are converted to objects, they generate a new object every time. So, the `UnboundMethod` object that would be returned is really not directly related to the method that was defined. Also, what would you want to do with an unbound method? The only case where *I* use an unbound method is to wrap an already existing method that I cannot modify; but if I have access to the definition anyway, then I don't need to wrap it.

A third group says that defining a method should evaluate to its name. This seems to be a somewhat arbitrary choice. In fact, I have not seen any compelling reason for why this should be the case. Literally the only argument is that this would allow you to make Ruby look more like Java:

```
# here's how you make a single method private today
def foo(bar) end
private :foo

# instead you could do this:
private def foo(bar) end
```

So, basically, the reason why method definitions return an implementation-defined value (which on most implementations is just `nil`) is that nobody has come up with a better suggestion.

Interestingly, `Module#define_method` *does* return something useful. If you use a method to define a method, it returns the old method. If you use a proc to define a method it returns a variation of that proc. If you use a block to define a method, it returns a proc corresponding to that block. In other words, it returns an executable object that corresponds to the method body:

```
class Foo
  $bar  = ->{}
  $baz  = define_method :baz, $bar

  $qux  = instance_method :baz
  $quux = define_method :quux, $qux

  define_method :corge do;end
end
# => #<Proc:0x1cda900@(irb):8 (lambda)>

$bar.eql?   $baz  # => true
$bar.equal? $baz  # => false
$qux.equal? $quux # => true
```

> Wouldn't it be useful if defining a class would evaluate as the class?

Why? The way it is now, class bodies can return anything you want, *including* the class. With your suggestion, it could return *only* the class, so it would be strictly less powerful.

Also, the only case were I ever needed a class body to return the class itself, was for getting a reference to the singleton class of an object, like this:

```
foo = Object.new
foo_singleton_class = class << foo; self end
```

Or the more well-known pattern:

```
class Object; def singleton_class; class << self; self end end end
```

But now that `Object#singleton_class` is part of the core library, that is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough review. There are a few things I don't feel particularly comfortable with, but they're all political and would probably fit better on a relevant mailing-list. But I do see how non-trivial it is to come-up with a consensus here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Defining a class does not evaluate to `nil`, it returns whatever was the last expression (like calling a method)

```
class X
  2
end  # => 2
```

A typical example is `singleton = class << SomeClass; self; end`, although now we can use `SomeClass.singleton_class`.

A method definition does return `nil` (which is why classes that end with a method definition return that `nil`). What would you like a method definition to return, and when would that be useful?

If you want the class to be returned, it's easy to end with `self`:

```
class X
  def foo
    :bar
  end

  self
end # => X
```

Comment: `class X; def f; 2; end; end  # => nil`

Comment: Indeed, but that's because the `def` returns `nil`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that functionality by calling Class.new{ ... } instead of using the class keyword.

```
someclass = Class.new{
  def bar
    puts "baz"
  end
}
```

and then you can name the class by assigning a constant to the class var.

```
Foo = someclass
```

so as this point you can do either of the following to instantiate the class:

```
instance1 = someclass.new
instance2 = Foo.new

instance1.bar  #=> baz
instance2.bar  #=> baz
```